# Testing apps on iOS 6 device using the wildcard provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4

I have spent the past 5 hours trying to make this work but unfortunately all attempts have failed. The process of testing apps on an actual iPhone is extremely frustrating for beginners such as myself compared to other platforms so I am hoping you guys can give me hints on what I am doing wrong here.

I have registered for an iOS developer account and paid the $99 and my account creation is completed. After letting Xcode do certificate registration, adding device and provisioning profiles I have the following automatically created for me:

In the developer portal - Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles

Under Certificates I have the following created:

- iOS Development
- iOS Distribution

Under Identifiers I have the following created:

- Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID

Under Devices I have the following created:

- My iPhone Name with its UDID

Under Provisioning Profiles I have the following created:

- iOS Team Provisioning Profile with its App ID set to Xcode iOS Wildcard App ID (*)

From what I've read, I should be able to test apps without having to create a new App ID as long as they don't use certain features that require App ID such as push notification.

So I went on and I created a new project in Xcode called HelloWorld. Running the application caused the error: `Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.test.HelloWorld' could not be found`

After reading some more articles (which all of them seem to be outdated as none reflect the new UI of the apple developer portal) I have done the following in Xcode:

Under Build Settings -> Code Signing and I set it to `iPhone Distribution: MyName (XXXXXXX)`
but that didn't fix anything.

So in short my question is how do I deploy and test an application to my device using this wildcard provisioning profile?

Comment: All you really have to do is: Open Xcode, Open "Window -> Organizer". Go to "Provisioning Profiles". Click "Refresh" bottom right. Log in with your dev Apple ID and Xcode will generate all required profiles.

Comment: @Krumelur Thanks alot man! That was it! I needed to refresh. I will accept this if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really have to do is: Open Xcode, Open "Window -> Organizer".
Go to "Provisioning Profiles".
Click "Refresh" bottom right.
Log in with your dev Apple ID and Xcode will generate all required profiles

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps (omit if you have done any of these, and I'm assuming that you've already created the certificates)

```
1 - Create a wildcard AppId e.g com.yourcompany.test.*
2 - Create a provisioning profile (development) using this identifier 
3 - Set identifier of your app to com.yourcompany.test.myapp
4 - Build & run it will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

First Check you have a valid status in your xcode>organiser

[image]

and you are signing with right dev. profile and make sure all your devices are added in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 you need to go to Xcode->Preferences.., go to the Accounts tab and select your apple id, then press "View details..". Finally press the refresh button.